# $state.go not working as expected in $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using $state.go with $stateChangeStart. After i log out, $state.go only change the url and not loading the template. It has no problem if i use $location.path('/signin'). This scenario occurs only after logout, but not before or after sign in.

```
angular.module('ma').run(function($rootScope, $location, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (isNotAuthenticate) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('signin', {}, {notify: false});
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: @RadimKöhler just implemented the solution. it is not working for my case. similar situation occurs. url changed on top, template not loaded but no error in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `notify:false` so no events will be emitted.

Simply use:

`$state.go('signin');`